# 'The application WhereAmI (com.paad.whereami) has stopped unexpectedly' Error

Tags: android

When I run the code shown below, this alert is display in the emulator:

> (Sorry! The application WhereAmI (com.paad.whereami) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. [Force Close])

If anyone know about this problem, please help me.

```
        LocationManager locationManager;
        locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        updateWithNewLocation(location);
    }
    private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location)
    {
        TextView myLocationText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);
        String latLongString;
        if(location!=null)
        {

            double lat=location.getLatitude();
            double lng=location.getLongitude();
            latLongString="Lat:"+lat+"\nLong:"+lng;
        }else{
            latLongString="No location found";
        }
        myLocationText.setText("Your current position is:\n"+latLongString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the complete logcat thing and the context of your code? Why, When Where?

Answer (score 0):

When the application is first running the

```
 locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

method might return null. You must implement LocationListener and inside the onLocationChanged method, initialize your location object.

for an indept discussion --

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/39239/1954